# Sending location information to the server using text file

Tags: android

This code is supposed to send data from a text file to a server. But its sending only the 1st line. how to move to next line of text file in android. And after sending I want to delete the line.
Basically I want to send the records according to the sequence they were stored.

```
 File file = new    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/BPCLTracker1/gpsdata.txt");
    File f1=new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/BPCLTracker1/gpsdata.txt");
    RandomAccessFile in = null;
    RandomAccessFile in1 = null;
    try
    {
      in = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
      in1= new RandomAccessFile(f1, "rw");}
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
      {// TODO Auto-generated catch bloc e.printStackTrace();}
      String line ="0";
      while (true)
      {
         try 
         {
            if (isInternetOn())
            {
               while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
               {
                     HttpEntity entity;
                     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     String url = "some url is here";
                     HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(line);
                     se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                     se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(
                     HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                     entity = se;
                     request.setEntity(entity);
                     HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                     entity = response.getEntity();
                     if (entity != null) {}
               }
           }
       }
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: did your code catch any exception while running?

Answer (score 0):

Upload you file like this

httpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
post.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);